# Inject with Spring Boot depending on properties from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, yaml

In one of our common libraries for our project I need to make an distinction between two implementations of an interface based on what Service is using it.

I inject this Interface via constructor injection and need to find out how I can make sure what implementation is used based on the value of a property in our application.yml.

I looked into the @Qualifier annotation but that does seem to need an attribute in an xml schema. We don't have such a thing.

In one part of our code we read out the properties for our KafkaListener this way

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{PathToProperties.getPrefix()}#OurBusinessProperties.getRelevantProperties()}"
```

Can I use the same syntax in Spring?

Comment: Check `@Value` annotation in Spring, mixed with `SpEL` expressions. Based on that value, you can manually fetch a bean from the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In one of our common libraries for our project I need to make an
>   distinction between two implementations of an interface based on what
>   Service is using it.

You can use profiles to do this.

Let's say you have two profiles: *production* and *test*.

Then you can annotate an implementation that you want to use in production like this:

```
@Profile("production")
@Component
class ProductionImplementation implements MyService {
}
```

And on another component set a different profile:

```
@Profile("test")
@Component
class TestImplementation implements MyService {
}
```

and then start your spring-boot application with the following argument:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=production
```

Alternatively you can select a profile using an environment variable:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = production
```

One more option is to create a factory that will create a different instance depending on some environmental configuration:

```
@Bean
public MyService myService() {
  if (condition) return FirstImplementation();
  return SecondImplementation();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is already very useful. But I already have profiles in both applications for dev, test, local, docker. 
like this:
spring:
  profiles: development
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 'kafka.development:9092'
Can I add something to it? Because both of the applications that use this library have the same profiles. 
Maybe with a topic?

Comment: You can always create a factory that will create a different instance depending some environment configuration. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked well in conjunction with the @Value annotation